# My image map covers my entire website, words, forms etc, how to solve?

Tags: html, css, image, dictionary, imagemap

image map in php

```
<html>
 <body>
 <img style="position: absolute; left:0; top: 0;" border="0" src="images/gen.jpg" usemap="#Map1">
 <map id="Map1" name="Map1">
 <area shape="rect" coords="136,331,211,351" name="home" a href="home.php">
 <area shape="rect" coords="136,379,244,400" name="aboutus" a href="aboutus.php">
 <area shape="rect" coords="136,426,247,447" name="calculate" a href="">
 <area shape="rect" coords="136,475,262,495" name="contactus" a href="">

</body>
 </html>
```

my css

```
 @charset "utf-8";
 /* CSS Document */

<style type="text/css">

A:link
 { text-decoration: none; color: black; cursor:crosshair; }
 A:visited
 { text-decoration: none; cursor:crosshair; color: black; }
 A:active
 { text-decoration: none; cursor:crosshair; color:black; }
 A:hover {
 text-decoration: none; color: #705551; background-color:black; font weight:none; cursor:help;}

 body 
{ background: #c0c2c3; 
font-family: georgia; 
color: #4a458d; 
font-size: 10pt;
 cursor: s-resize;


}

td
 { font-family: Verdana;
 font-size: 10px; 
color: #4a458d; 
cursor: crosshair; 
text-align: left;
 margin: 0px;}
 }

textarea, input, select {
 font-family : trebuchet ms; 
font-size: 10px; 
color:#4a458d;
 cursor: crosshair;
 border-color: silver; 
border-style: solid; 
border-top-width: 1px; 
border-left-width: 1px;
 border-right-width: 1px; 
border-bottom-width: 1px;
 }


.head 
{font-family: georgia; 
font-weight: none;
 letter-spacing:-3px;
 font-size: 17pt; 
line-height: 16pt;
 color: #48457b;
 border-top: 0px solid;
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 border-right: 0px solid;
 border-color: none;
 background-color:#c0c2c3;
 text-align: left;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 }

.head2 
{font-family: georgia; 
font-weight: none;
 letter-spacing:2px;
 font-size: 7pt; 
line-height: 10pt;
 color: #443f80;
 border-top: 0px solid;
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 border-right: 0px solid;
 border-color: none;
 background-color:#c0c2c3;
 text-align: left;
 text-transform: none;
 }
```

my log in page code in php

```
<html>
<body>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <?php
 include("map.php"); 
?> 
<form method="post" action="checklogin.php">
 <table width="450" height="88" border="0" align="left">
 <tr>
 <td width="180">Enter your email</td>
 <td width="270">
 <input name="email" type="text" size="30" /></td>
 <tr>
 <td>Enter your password</td>
 <td><input type="password" name="password" type="text" size="30" /></td></tr>

<tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" /></td></tr></table>


</form>
 </div>

</body></html>
```

i dont know what's wrong, but whatever i type in my login page wont appear unless i remove my image map, it is hidden behind the image map, but i want it to appear on my image map, beside the navigations on the left.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with PHP, I've added the html and css tags.

Comment: Tables and image maps.. time to learn some more modern techniques.

Comment: Wait, are you calling the HTML file with the image map "map.php", opening and closing the <body> tag in it, closing (but not opening) the <html> tag in it, and including it in another HTML file with its own <body> and <html> tags? WHY?!

Answer (score 0):

you are using a position:absolute on your image.  Add a z-index:1; and then wrap the rest in a container, also with an absolute, and give it a z-index:2

**EDIT**

One page solution, still bad form, but:

```
<html>
<head> 
    <style>

    A:link
     { text-decoration: none; color: black; cursor:crosshair; }
     A:visited
     { text-decoration: none; cursor:crosshair; color: black; }
     A:active
     { text-decoration: none; cursor:crosshair; color:black; }
     A:hover {
     text-decoration: none; color: #705551; background-color:black; font weight:none; cursor:help;}

     body 
    { background: #c0c2c3; 
    font-family: georgia; 
    color: #4a458d; 
    font-size: 10pt;
     cursor: s-resize;


    }

    td
     { font-family: Verdana;
     font-size: 10px; 
    color: #4a458d; 
    cursor: crosshair; 
    text-align: left;
     margin: 0px;}
     }

     .imap{
         position: absolute; left:0; top: 0; z-index:1;
     }
     .pgwrap{
         position:absolute; left:0; top: 0; z-index:2;
     }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="pgwrap">
        <div class="imap">
         <img style="" border="0" src="images/gen.jpg" usemap="#Map1">
         <map id="Map1" name="Map1">
         <area shape="rect" coords="136,331,211,351" name="home" a href="home.php">
         <area shape="rect" coords="136,379,244,400" name="aboutus" a href="aboutus.php">
         <area shape="rect" coords="136,426,247,447" name="calculate" a href="">
         <area shape="rect" coords="136,475,262,495" name="contactus" a href="">
         </map>
        </div>

        <form method="post" action="checklogin.php">
         <table width="450" height="88" border="0" align="left">
         <tr>
         <td width="180">Enter your email</td>
         <td width="270">
         <input name="email" type="text" size="30" /></td>
         <tr>
         <td>Enter your password</td>
         <td><input type="password" name="password" size="30" /></td></tr>
         </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" /></td></tr></table>


        </form>

    </div>
</body>
```

This ^ is what I was talking about.

Comment: Something like:

<div class="classname"> 
<?php
 include("map.php"); 
?> 
...rest of code...
</form>
 </div>
</div>

And then add your rules to your css file.  As everyone else is (sometimes rudely) pointing out though, you are using extremely outdated code.  Also inline styling, etc...  Your php file should also not include the body and html tags. I understand this is all probably in rough format right now, but you may want to consider seriously revising your direction.

Answer (score 0):

## Quick and dirty solution

Change the following line

```
<img style="position: absolute; left:0; top: 0;" border="0" src="images/gen.jpg" usemap="#Map1">
```

To something like this

```
<img id="myMap" src="images/gen.jpg" usemap="#Map1">
```

and in your CSS file add

```
#myMap {
position: absolute;
left:0; 
top: 0;
border:0;
z-index:-999;
}
```

Complete code here: http://pastebin.com/3HnhkJ8x -- Tested on latest versions of Chrome and Firefox, not tested on IE.

## Recommended solution

You are using techniques that have become *greatly* discouraged a long time ago, such as:

- Image maps
- Tables used for formatting purposes

Also, you're mixing inline CSS and a separate CSS file; and apparently you're using PHP to include a HTML file inside another HTML file, each file having its own  and  tags.

I strongly advise you study and improve your HTML and CSS knowledge and learn best industry practices.

Comment: sorry, just on my first project and these are the basics taught by my teacher, following your quick and dirty solution, my texts are still not appearing :/

Comment: Hmm the form did appear now, however it's still not on top of the image. I'm actually following this webpage's layout as a reference http://epilogueee.blogspot.com, so my background is somewhat similar

Comment: @YSingapore I've tested on Chrome and Firefox and this is the result: http://i.imgur.com/WvmuETZ.png -- form on top, image on bottom. Clickable and fillable. What browser(s), including versions, are you using?

Comment: wow that looks awesome! ohyeah, it works on firefox, I'm using the latest version of IE